# Indoor/outdoor image recognition

Tags: matlab, opencv

Is it possible to download a source code for indoor/outdoor image recognition? I have found some papers about it, but not source code. In MATLAB or OpenCV it would be great.

Comment: What do you need to be recognized?  Just the distinction of whether the image is indoors or outdoors?

Comment: yes, just that, nothing more...input: outdoor/indoor image; output: Message("This is outdoor/indoor image...");

Comment: what if it's in a window? is that inside or outside?

Comment: i do not know, i think, it is just a exception, so it can be ignored?